# vim: NERDTree how to: create/rename/move file/directory

Tags: vim

I checked the documentation of `NERDTree`, but didn't find the way to create new file/directory or rename/move it (once I'm browsing directory tree).

In the `netrw` plugin it would be easy, but this one is not used any more as `NERDTree` just replaced it. And I don't want to look back.

Anyone ready to point me to the right direction?

Comment: Put you cursor in the nerdTree window, ant hit 'm', you will get the hint

Comment: whenever you are looking for something just hit the ? key. this will bring the nerdtree help, which you can easily search via the / key

Comment: @FredericClose I pressed it, however I didn't notice there is "Show menu" option, as this would not associate in my head with file copy/move/...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a little bit hidden behind a menu (see `:help NERDTreeMenu`), but as an upside it is extensible. It is launched (for the current file node) with the <kbd>m</kbd> key by default.

> ```
> The script comes with two default menu plugins: exec_menuitem.vim and
> fs_menu.vim. fs_menu.vim adds some basic filesystem operations to the menu for
> creating/deleting/moving/copying files and dirs. exec_menuitem.vim provides a
> menu item to execute executable files.
> ```